# ManyToMany relationship fixing

Tags: mysql, sql, database, split

I have following legacy database setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category_ids` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

in which `category_ids` is a string of category id's separated by comas: `1, 10, 15, 6`. Is there a way to convert this database to more conventional one (using three tables, one for storing relationships), using only SQL and no other scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have CROSS APPLY or recursive CTEs, which would be the simplest routes.

But you're only dong this once, so you only need a quick hack.

First, find out the maximum number of items in the category list...

```
SELECT
  MAX(LEN(category_ids) - LEN(REPLACE(category_ids, ',', '')) + 1) AS max_items
FROM
  items
```

Then you can do something like this...

```
SELECT
  items.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      items.category_ids,
      ',',
      map.id  -- Get the first 'n' items from the list
    ),
    ',',
    -1        -- Get the last item from (the first 'n' items from the list)
  ) AS category_id
FROM
  items
INNER JOIN
(
            SELECT 1 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 as id
  etc, etc, up to the max number of items found previously
)
  AS map
    ON LEN(items.category_ids) - LEN(REPLACE(items.category_ids, ',', '')) + 1 >= map.id
```

I haven't tested it, but I'm assuming that `SUBSTRING_INDEX('last', ',', -1)` returns `'last'`.

I'm no MySQL expert, so this may not be optimal, but as a one time quick win thistype of structure should work...

Comment: I wish there was a way to generate map table independent of max numbers. Now it seems to work, though not optimally, but who cares as long as it works? :)

Comment: BTW, we can use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` and MySQL currently don't have `LEN` function, it is `LENGTH` there.

Comment: @Shark - Union has an added overhead of de-duplication.  Union All doesn't.  If you don't care about, or need, de-duplication then it's advisable to use Union All.